# open modal in the index page loaded from partial view

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-partialview, bootstrap-modal

I’m loading index page content through a partial view. I want to open a bootstrap modal dialog inside this partial view. but nothing happens if i click on the button. can we not include another controller inside a partial view?

My partial view is loaded through ng-view. is it because of scope issues? My app.js is below:

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/p1', {
    templateUrl: 'app/partials/view1.html',
    controller: 'mainController'
}).when('/p2', {
    templateUrl: 'app/partials/view2.html',
    controller: 'secondController'
}).when('/p3', {
    templateUrl: 'app/partials/view3.html',
    controller: 'thirdController'
}).when('/p4', {
    templateUrl: 'app/partials/view4.html',
    controller: 'fourthController'
}).when('/p5', {
    templateUrl: 'app/partials/view5.html',
    controller: 'fifthController'
}).otherwise({
    redirectTo : '/p1'
});
```

}]);

Comment: More code please, like the contents of the partial view and the code you're using to open the modal.  A plunker or jsfiddle would be nice.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/UnZyycROWyID6h22biFZ

Comment: Can you get the plunk to work, at least switching views and using the right controllers?  You need to ask a separate question if it's about getting the routes to work.

Comment: Voting to close the question as it seems to be to narrow a focus and just an error getting everything set up.  I added all the modules (angular, angular-route, bootstrap, angular-ui) to your plnkr, added the missing files, and set the correct controller names in your route config and it works for me.  [(***plnkr***)](http://plnkr.co/edit/VHFFGCmg3led3qD2xgHK?p=preview)